# Naming files with decimal numbers in BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, filenames

I want to name my files with the step in which they were created. The step size is in decimals and as far as I know dealing with decimals in bash is difficult. This is the code:

```
for i in $(seq 0.05 0.05 0.45) 
do
.
.
.
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_$(( i*2 )).vasp
done
```

The error I'm getting is below:

```
./slip_loop.sh: line 3: 0.05: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".05")
```

Expected file names:

```
slipped_112_111_0.10.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.20.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.30.vasp
.
.
.
```

Please let me know if there's any fix for this. Thanks.

Comment: @AdminBee I forgot to mention that the POSCAR gets created again when the loop starts. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bash` shell does not do floating point arithmetics.

This means that you can't use floating point values the way you want.  Instead you could use

```
for number in {1..9}; do
    # other code here

    printf -v name 'slipped_112_111_0.%d0.vasp' "$number"
    mv POSCAR "$name"
done
```

The `printf -v` statement prints directly into the variable `name`. The format string formats the number so that it occurs in the correct place in the name of your new file.

This would execute the following `mv` commands:

```
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.10.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.20.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.30.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.40.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.50.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.60.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.70.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.80.vasp
mv POSCAR slipped_112_111_0.90.vasp
```

If you need the floating point numbers for something else:

```
for number in {1..9}; do
    # other code here

    value=$( bc <<<"scale=2; $number/20" )

    printf -v name 'slipped_112_111_0.%d0.vasp' "$number"
    mv POSCAR "$name"
done
```

Comment: I somewhat assume the OP wants to use the floating-point values as input parameters to the process that generates the `POSCAR` file in the first place (but then again, this wasn't explicitly stated in the question) ...

Comment: @AdminBee I made an edit to address this.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks for pointing out.
@Kusalananda The second option worked. I can used the the value of variable ```value``` for further calculation. Thanks. Looks like when it comes to decimals and bash, I'll have to resort to workarounds every time.

Comment: Apart from using ksh93 (which does do floats), there are several commands that work well: awk, bc, dc are in every distro. Perl, python etc are in Linux but not some Unix. External commands use CPU to start processes. But numbers are only strings until you need to hit them with a math operator.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do decimal arithmetic: make strings.

Your example only varies one digit anyway. A more general version:

```
paul $ for i in {010..200..10}; do
> echo "${i:0:1}.${i:1:2}"
> done
0.10
0.20
0.30
0.40
0.50
0.60
0.70
0.80
0.90
1.00
1.10
1.20
1.30
1.40
1.50
1.60
1.70
1.80
1.90
2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple to perform arithmetic (add, substract, multiply, etc) with floating numbers in the shell.

But most shells could print floating point numbers:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0.10 0.1 0.9); do printf '%5.3f  ' "$i"; done
0.100  0.200  0.300  0.400  0.500  0.600  0.700  0.800  0.900
```

Which will become:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0.10 0.1 0.9); do printf 'slipped_112_111_%5.3f.vasp\n' "$i"; done
slipped_112_111_0.100.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.200.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.300.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.400.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.500.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.600.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.700.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.800.vasp
slipped_112_111_0.900.vasp
```

Doing math in the shell needs bc, or awk.

```
$ printf '%5.3f" "$(echo "0.3321 + 0.3625" | bc -l)"
0.695
```